# How to map converted time as a string in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const posts = [
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <p>{post.displayDate}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to convert the time to something like `2020.12.29` as in the following

```
let today = new Date("2020-12-29T03:00:00.000Z");   

let year = today.getFullYear();
let month = today.getMonth() + 1;
let day = today.getDate();

console.log(year + '.' + month + '.' + day)
```

How would I organize my code to map my dates in the above format?

My [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/convert-time-kpun9?file=/src/App.js:0-498)

Comment: If it is going to be in ISO 8601, you can use `"2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z".substr(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working App: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/convert-time-forked-406iy?file=/src/App.js:284-654)

[image]

```js
return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {posts.map((post) => {
        const date = new Date(post.displayDate);
        return (
          <p key={date.toString()}>
            {date.getFullYear()}. {date.getMonth() + 1}. {date.getDate()}
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: You probably want to save `new Date(post.displayDate)` in a variable.

Comment: right, it will make the code a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Make `convert()` method and use it inside JSX.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const posts = [
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ];

  const convert = (inputDate) => {
    let date = new Date(inputDate);   

    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let day = date.getDate();

    return year + '.' + month + '.' + day;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <p>{convert(post.displayDate)}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would place the convert function outside the component though

Comment: Here is what I think is better-formated code with this idea. Also, read comments in code for extra info @ElijahLee [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions65592855how-to-map-converted-time-as-a-string-in-react-comment-1-y5t2n)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line of code. Please let me know if this is what you want.

```
<p>{new Date(post.displayDate).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
```

Comment: You can also find a list of different types of date formats as you like.
https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format)? A running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/convert-time-forked-ru2n1

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const formatDate = (date) => {
  const d = new Date(date);
  const ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { year: "numeric" }).format(d);
  const mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { month: "numeric" }).format(d);
  const da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { day: "2-digit" }).format(d);
  return `${ye}.${mo}.${da}`;
};

export default function App() {
  const posts = [
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      displayDate: "2020-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <p>{formatDate(post.displayDate)}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```